# Countdown Timer using php to activate a button click

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Need a help guyz, my scenario is - In my database i am having a table with a column "created_time" which stores the current system time in HH:MM AM/PM. Now I want as soon as the data entered in that table with current system time then in one of my php page there will be a button named "Start Exam", currently the button will be in "disabled" state, it should be enabled exactly after 1 hour of the time entered in the database along with a countdown timer showing along with the button.

Can anyone help me out with that.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where does you code fail? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Binarus..............This part is completely new for me. So i don't know how to start that's why no code.

Comment: @Binarus............I have done the timer part for the ongoing exam. Means once the exam starts there is a countdown timer which when comes to zero then the exam ends. Now i stuck at this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $dateFromDB ?>").getTime();
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    // do something when time is expired 
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```